# Windows Service Stuck on "Starting"

Tags: c#

I've just created and installed my first Windows Service. When I start the service is never changes it's status to "Started". The status stays "Starting" but the service is doing it's job. I thought that perhaps the way I'm interacting with the OnStart method. I simply get the OnStart method to call another method that executes fine. Here is a sample:

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try { 
                Logger("Start");
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string filePath2 = @"C:/ProgramData/Error.txt";

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath2, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine + "Message: " + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

What would I need to change to get the client to register that the service has started and is running. PS, the service is doing what it's meant to do.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

EDIT

This is what Logger does:

```
public void Logger(string state)
    {
        try
        {
            {
                Random a = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
                //unique name PhoneSystem.ApplicationName = "TestApi";//any name
                PhoneSystem.ApplicationName = PhoneSystem.ApplicationName + a.Next().ToString();
            }

            #region phone system initialization(init db server)
            String filePath = @"C:/ProgramData/3CXLogger/3CXPhoneSystem.ini";
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                //this code expects 3CXPhoneSystem.ini in current directory.
                //it can be taken from the installation folder (find it in Program Files/3CXPhone System/instance1/bin for in premiss installation)
                //or this application can be run with current directory set to location of 3CXPhoneSystem.ini

                //v14 (cloud and in premiss) installation has changed folder structure.
                //3CXPhoneSystem.ini which contains connectio information is located in 
                //<Program Files>/3CX Phone System/instanceN/Bin folder.
                //in premiss instance files are located in <Program Files>/3CX Phone System/instance1/Bin
                throw new Exception("Cannot find 3CXPhoneSystem.ini");
            }
            String value = _3cxLogger.Utilities.GetKeyValue("ConfService", "ConfPort", filePath);
            Int32 port = 0;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                Int32.TryParse(value.Trim(), out port);
                PhoneSystem.CfgServerPort = port;
            }
            value = _3cxLogger.Utilities.GetKeyValue("ConfService", "confUser", filePath);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                PhoneSystem.CfgServerUser = value;
            value = _3cxLogger.Utilities.GetKeyValue("ConfService", "confPass", filePath);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                PhoneSystem.CfgServerPassword = value;
            #endregion
            DN[] ps = PhoneSystem.Root.GetDN(); //Access PhoneSystem.Root to initialize ObjectModel
            //_3cxLogger.SampleStarter.StartSample(args);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string filePath2 = @"C:\ProgramData\3CXLogger\Error.txt";

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath2, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine + "Message: " + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        string constring = "Data Source = LEWCOMP1\\COMPLIANCE; Initial Catalog = 3CXCallStats; Integrated Security = True";


        while (state == "Start")
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (DN dn in PhoneSystem.Root.GetDN())
            {
                ActiveConnection[] a = dn.GetActiveConnections();
                foreach (ActiveConnection ac in a)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (ac.Status == ConnectionStatus.Connected)
                        {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine + ex.Source);
                        string filePath2 = @"C:\ProgramData\3CXLogger\Error.txt";

                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath2, true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine + "Message: " + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            count = count / 2;
            string update = "UPDATE callsCounter SET Counter = '" + count + "' WHERE ID='1';";
            string insert = "INSERT Interval_Counter (Date_Time, Count) VALUES ('" + DateTime.Now + "','" + count + "')";
            SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand updateCMD = new SqlCommand(update, myCon);
            SqlCommand insertCMD = new SqlCommand(insert, myCon);
            SqlDataReader myReaderUpdate;
            SqlDataReader myReaderInsert;

            myCon.Open();
            myReaderUpdate = updateCMD.ExecuteReader();
            myReaderUpdate.Read();
            myCon.Close();


            myCon.Open();
            myReaderInsert = insertCMD.ExecuteReader();
            myReaderInsert.Read();
            myCon.Close();
        }
    }
```

Additionaly, I checked the event logs and there are events for the service has successfully started. Odd.

Comment: What does `Logger` do?

Comment: `c:/ProgramData` isn't a valid path. It should be `C:\ProgramData`. This means that no log will be produced. Additionally, your application should *NOT* write in `C:\ProgramData` directly, nor hard code the path to the %APPDATA% folder. it should create an application folder under the folder pointed by the environment variable. Better yet, use `Environemt.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` as [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @MitchelStuartFountaine note the rest of the comment. You should get access to the path through the environment because the path *does* change and user applications shouldn't have access outside *their* data folder.

Comment: Do you have any errors in Event Viewer? Windows + R, eventvwr, Enter. Windows Logs, System

Comment: Don't try to create your own logging mechanism. There are a lot of great, battle-tested logging libraries. Logging is one of the things that you simply have to be able to trust, as you found out.

Comment: Also there is restriction for Windows Service starting time. You must not to do any long operation in OnStart method. You should execute OnStart as fast as possible. All other things you can do in new thread.

Comment: And is this concatenation of a SQL string? Are you sure that `count` is what you think it is? What if it is serialized as `21,5` instead of `21.5`? This *will* happen if the code runs eg on a French, German or Greek system (most of Europe actually)

Comment: Thanks @ArtavazdBalayan, I will look into how I can start a new thread that starts my Logging method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help!

I created a new class and started a new thread that targeted the method.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Log oLog = new Log();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oLog.Logger));
        t.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  This solution was exactly what was needed in my case.